# Visual Studio Code [Ubuntu 16.04] - Running the code

Tags: visual-studio, ubuntu

I have a few issues with Visual Studio and I would like for it to function slightly more like Geany.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and when running cpp in Geany it opens a terminal for me when running the code. This allows for me to interact with the program that was written (ie. input values etc.).

Visual Studio utilizes json, which I admit that I am still trying to figure out for the most part. I have downloaded a few extensions (ie. codeRunner). This runs the code in the output box but does not allow for me to input any values etc. Most of the coding that is being done is for class, all of which is in C++.

Questions:

How can I get Visual Studio Code to open a terminal to run the code? I'd be fine with the output box at the bottom, I just can not figure out how to get it to allow me to input or interact with the program.

Secondly, Visual Studio will NOT run any files that have  in the title. Instructor sends a ton of files that I have to trouble shoot to get to run and they include spaces in the title.

I think that's it. If you can even point me in the right directions to solve these I'd' be happy. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean the *integrated terminal*? If so, try the shortcut [ctrl + `]

Comment: I can do the integrated terminal, I would really like to be able to 'click' run and it do it by itself.. Lazy I know :)